# Questions on proving in Math Olympiad

Tags: geometry, contest-math

In a square ABCD with length 1cm, let P and Q be 2 points on AD and AB respectively. When P and Q are connected, the right angle triangle PAQ has a perimeter of 2cm.
Prove or disprove that PQ will always be 1cm.

I have tried using putting triangle PAQ in a circle and letting PQ be the diameter. However, I do not know how to continue from there.

Comment: Let the length of $PQ$ be $L$. Find the length of  $AP$ and $AQ$ using trigonometry assuming angle $APQ$ to be any value $\theta$. Now sum up the length of the sides  of the triangle which is given to be $2$. What can you conclude about $L$?

Comment: Think of the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Let consider case when $AP=AQ$, then $PQ^2=AP^2+AQ^2 \Rightarrow PQ=AP\sqrt{2}$.
$AP+AQ+PQ=2\Rightarrow AP(2+\sqrt{2})=2 \Rightarrow AP=\frac{2}{2+\sqrt{2}} < 1$. $PQ=AP\sqrt{2}=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{2+\sqrt{2}} \neq 2$. Disproven by counterexample.